# Backbone, trigger view event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Hi I'm trying to trigger a view event after some dom modification inside the view initialize function

Edit: sorry for my question, it was not clear. Here a full code sample. At the end i figured out that i was triggering the change event before adding the class..feeling so stupid but i struggled for hours! 
Thank you for your support!

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var App = {};

    (function($) {

        App.FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
                events: {
                    "change .autofill" : "autofill"
                },

                initialize : function() {
                    _.bindAll(this, "autofill");

                    this.formelements = {"input" : {"autofill" : true}};

                    for(var elementId in this.formelements){
                        if(this.formelements[elementId].autofill){
                            var $el = $("#"+elementId);
                            //$el.trigger("change").addClass("autofill")//does not work trigger before class added :-(
                            $el.addClass("autofill").trigger("change");
                        }
                    }
                },

                autofill : function(e){
                    console.log("ok");
                }
        });     

        App.init = function(containerId){
            new App.FormView({el : "#"+containerId});
        }
    })(jQuery);
    </script>


    <div id="container">
        <input type="checkbox" id="input" />
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        App.init("container");
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverfow. What is the question? If you get any error, please paste the error. You cannot just add source code, and believe that someone will understand what do you mean

Comment: What exactly you mean by  *"does not work"*..? What is `elementId`..? We need to see the DOM structure to even make sure such an element exists. Please share a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to trigger an event on an element that is not yet in the DOM. That's not going to work, you will have to trigger your event after the view has rendered.

I don't know exactly how you're rendering but consider [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/eMtOLdYCt1tc95UFjX5k?p=preview)

```
var View = Backbone.View.extend({

  events: {
    'change input': 'autofill'
  },

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<input>');
    this.$('input').trigger('change');
  },

  autofill: function(e) {
    console.log('ohai thar');
  }

});

var view = new View({
  el: $('#root')
});
view.render();
```

When the event is triggered on an element that is added to the document it gets picked up.

Comment: Why do you think element is not yet in DOM..?

Comment: @TJ Because the OP says it doesn't work and I can't see any other reason why it shouldn't work than `$("#"+elementId)` returning an empty set.

Comment: Then you should ask for more code to make sure that is the case. This is just an assumption... You can't make a statement like *"You're trying to trigger an event on an element that is not yet in the DOM"* with the information provided by OP. You should be voting to close the question instead

Comment: @TJ So what you're saying is that this wouldn't work even if the element was in the DOM when the attempt to trigger the event was done. That is false. I would have voted to close if I thought the question was unclear but I don't so I didn't.

Comment: No, I'm saying you can't make a statement like *"You're trying to trigger an event on an element that is not yet in the DOM"* with the information provided. There is not enough information to make such a statement. You don't know the value of `elementId`, you don't know what is in DOM. These things are **not clear**. so the question should be put on hold untill such things are clear rather than people posting answers based on assumptions. You seem to have enough rep to know that and have the privileges to take necessary action